# Horizontal scrolling between activities in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

I'm building a new application to the Android platform and I want to implement moving between different activities by scrolling. I want also to use some kind of scrolling effect like in this [example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

I've searched the web and found a couple of examples using [view pager](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/) and [fragments](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/), but my problems are:

1. View pager is used to switch between views and I want to switch between different activities.
2. I don't want to use fragments because I don't think it's going to fit to earlier API (before Android 2.1).

So, for my questions:

1. Is there any other way for doing it, except of using onFling gesture and then losing the sliding effect?
2. Can I use fragments to the earlier API's?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use fragments, the android sdk comes with a [support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) that backports fragments down to android 1.6. and newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible to use fragments in lower versions. You simply have use the android support library and impost viewpager to your app. Here is a very good example which uses View Pager and fortunately it implements the support libraries and it worked for me from android 2.1.

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: Do you know if these support libraries is working with API 3?

Comment: yes checked just now. You inherit the support library and iw works like a charm. not a problem

Comment: I don't think you right, take a look at that [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use fragments in earlier versions, using android-support-v4.
If you work with Eclipse, you can add it to your project by right-click on it, "Android Tools", then "Add Support Library... "